# Friend in front of whom I have badmouthed the company is becoming a colleague

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, new-job, ethics

So a couple of months ago I was pretty close with a friend of mine and among other things we have talked about our jobs. I have told him that I'm not (very) happy at mine and that there are things that I like about it - i.e. the atmosphere is good, it is a fun place to be, but there are things that I don't like - i.e. the salaries are lower than those offered at other companies and I have also shared with him that I am contemplating quitting and have interviewed with other companies.

At some point we drifted apart (no bad feelings, just started seeing each other much less often) and when we recently met he told me that he will be starting work at my company soon (the same I have badmouthed some time ago in front of him).

I hope that I'm overthinking it, but I feel a bit nervous and negative about us working together. I feel awkward that he knows so much about how I feel about my job - I have discussed the things that I dislike about the company with my boss (i.e. salary) - but I doubt that he knows about my interviews at other companies and so on. I'm afraid that we may even end up working at the same team (hopefully not).

Is there something I should be worried about (even in worst case scenario)? How should I act?

Comment: If he or she says anything, then it's all lies, you've never said anything like that, and you would never have said anything like that to this person, who isn't and never has been your friend. If nothing is said, you do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, guys! @JoeStrazzere, I don't know - after interviewing at few other places I'm starting to think that my job is actually not as bad as I used to think and I may as well stay there. I'm a bit afraid that I might have jeopardized it in a way due to my complaints in front of this guy.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Yes, if that ex-friend doesn't have the common sense to keep his mouth shut about things that would be very damaging, then he or she is retroactively unfriended, and you do whatever you can do deflect the damage.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there something I should be worried about (even in worst case scenario)? How should I act?

Act the same as usual, welcome your friend aboard etc,. everyone knows private rants and work are two separate things. There is zero chance of him discussing your months old rants with your boss since he's just walked in the door himself.

Comment: The chance is very low indeed, but sometimes fact is stranger than fiction.

Comment: @jpmc26 the chance is zero, but if he did so, he's just making himself look bad. I'd just laugh it off 'Yeah boss, no big deal I was just ranting after a bad day. No idea why he'd bring it up with you.'

Answer (score 4):

> Is there something I should be worried about (even in worst case scenario)?

Everyone, including your manager, has grumbled to friends about their job.  You should not be worried at all about your friend starting.  Your friend has an incentive to keep your grumbling to himself as well - if he does tell anyone at the company, he's just marked himself as a snitch.

If he does snitch on you, simply deny everything.

Comment: Why would you lie?

Answer (score 2):

> How should I act?

Speak truthfully.

It looks like you are still at that company after several months. It can't be *that* bad there.

Your friend started working there, despite what you have told him.

> I have discussed the things that I dislike about the company with my boss (i.e. salary) - but I doubt that he knows about my interviews at other companies and so on.

Having interviews with other companies is something everybody can do at any time. Even if you haven't explicitly told your boss that you had interviews at other companies, it doesn't take much imagination to assume that an employee not satisfied in his current job is looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend has his reasons for joining your company, just as you had your own reasons for doing so. And he will eventually have his own reasons for looking to join another company, just as you have yours. His circumstances are his, your circumstances are yours and it is really counterproductive of you to try to read into his situation from your perspective - never mind that his situation is his business and none of yours to begin with.

Focus on getting your job done. If you are looking for new employment, go into radio silence about that at least for the time being.

Everybody has their own perspective. What's terrible to you may be wonderful to him. And again, you may not have the same priorities and objectives. Let him live his own life and focus on living yours. And quit any temptation to pass judgement on his life choices based on your perspective. What doesn't work for you may just be wonderful for him. You are entitled to your own life and your own judgement. Just as he is entitled to his.